# How to place ありました with the 〜んです pattern, and the meaning of the resulting sentence

Tags: translation, meaning

There is a question in Minna no Nihongo, where I need to fit in ありました with the 〜んです pattern, such that the sentence makes sense.

おそかったですね。なにか _________ か。

How shall I fit it in, and what meaning will it give to the sentence?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm??? We normally say 遅かったですね。何かあったんですか？

Comment: The speaker had asked the listener to bring several things, and the speaker guessed that the listener was late because he couldn't find some of them?

Comment: I'm not sure "Isn't there anything?" is a very fitting translation for 「なにか なかったんですか」. Perhaps something more like "Was something not [there]?" or "Was something missing?" would be more apt.

Comment: A:「何か食べるものを探してきてください。」 B:「はい、行ってきます。」・・・(１時間後) B:「ただいま。」 A:「おそかったですね。何か(食べるものは)なかったんですか？」 B:「はい、探したけど、何もありませんでした。」... ←とか？

Comment: @HitomiHigurashi Please explain the context. The answer highly depends on the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change ありました into the plain form, あった, to be followed by んです:

> [遅]{おそ}かったですね。[何]{なに}かあったんですか。
>   You're late. What happened?
>   (Lit. [You] were late. Did anything happen?)